# How to use Custom Dialog xml based in Compose in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog

I have existing `Dialog` view in `xml` based. I want to use `Dialog` view in my `Compose` feature. Is it possible to do that? If yes, Can you provide me any guidance? example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this way

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#compose-in-fragments

basically they suggest to use `AndroidViewBinding` which is provided by the androidx. compose. ui:ui-viewbinding library

example is showing in fragment but you can just use it in dialog as you just need to use binding